# Issues with understanding multiple joins

Tags: sql, postgresql, rails-postgresql

I have the following tables:

```
users
 ____________
| id         |
| first_name |
|____________|

pre_task_plans
 ____________
| id         |
| creator_id | (fk user_id)
|____________|

pre_task_plan_users
 __________________
| id               |
| user_id          |
| pre_task_plan_id |
|__________________|
```

I am trying to get all users for pre_task_plans where I am the creator of (users.id 1)

I have

```
SELECT users.*
FROM users
JOIN pre_task_plans as ptp on ptp.creator_id = 1
JOIN pre_task_plan_users as ptpu on ptpu.pre_task_plan_id = ptp.id
```

But it is returning users that are not in pre_task_plan_users related to my pre_task_plans. What am I not understanding about how the 2nd JOIN is working?

PSQL 9.6.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT users.*, other.*
FROM users
JOIN pre_task_plans as ptp on ptp.creator_id = users.id
JOIN pre_task_plan_users as ptpu on ptpu.pre_task_plan_id = ptp.id
join users as other on pre_task_plan_users.user_id = other.id
where users.id = 1
```

You join each `pre_task_plan` to the `user` it created, and then you shrink the results down to you as user (so only those you created).

You should display some rows from `pre_task_plans` as well, like this you only see your own `id` and `first_name`

Comment: I only want to see `users.*` specifically from the `pre_task_plan_users` table where I was the creator of the pre_task_plan.

Comment: This only returns the creator

Comment: Thanks, the `other` join is exactly what I was missing. I have `SELECT other.*
FROM users
JOIN pre_task_plans AS ptp ON ptp.creator_id = users.id
JOIN pre_task_plan_users AS ptpu ON ptpu.pre_task_plan_id = ptp.id
JOIN users AS other ON ptpu.user_id = other.id
WHERE users.id = 1
ORDER BY ptp.created_at DESC`

Comment: @theartofbeing then you can shrink it down to `SELECT other.* FROM pre_task_plans AS ptp JOIN pre_task_plan_users AS ptpu ON ptpu.pre_task_plan_id = ptp.id JOIN users AS other ON ptpu.user_id = other.id WHERE ptp.creator_id = 1 ORDER BY ptp.created_at DESC` - you do not need anything from the first "users" - the `where` can be applied to the `creator_id` directly

Comment: bonus question...how can I `select distinct on users.id` while ordering by `ptp.created_at`?

Comment: @theartofbeing sql without data is hard :) and there is no `created_at` in the tablesdescriptions you provided - for distinct you can either use a group_by user.id and first_name with a  min(ptp.created_at) if you are only interested in the earliest ptp for each user - if the same user was created_at mutliple times? Might be better to post a new question with new tables and some demodata + expected result. SqlFiddle would be cool.